# SQL query for filtering all rows with a particular value in at least one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table T with data like this:

```
ID    |    Status
-----------------
1     |    X
2     |    Y
1     |    Z
3     |    P
4     |    Q
3     |    Z
```

I need to retrieve all the rows where the ID does not have status Z in that or any other rows.
So, for the above example table, I need my query to to return the following table:

```
ID    |    Status
-----------------
2     |    Y
4     |    Q
```

Rows with ID 1 and 3 were discarded because they had at least one row with the value Z as Status.

What's a good and efficient query for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude the ids with the `Z` status using the subquery .

```
select * from datas 
where id not in ( select id from  datas 
                            where status ='Z' );
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/2

As @IVO GELOV suggested you can use `EXISTS`;

```
select d.id,d.status 
from datas d 
where  not exists  ( select id from  datas e 
                               where status ='Z'  and d.id=e.id);
```

Comment: You may want to use the `not exists` predicate - it could be slightly faster than `not in`

Answer (score 1):

Here the inner query will return 1,3 as the id and while checking the returned data the outer query will return 2,4 as the returned id with status

**NOT In Query**

```
select id,status from T
where id not in
(select id from T where status='Z');

                   **OR**
```

**NOT Exists Query**

```
select ext_alias.id,ext_alias.status from T ext_alias
where not exists 
(select id from T inn_alias where inn_alias.status='Z' and inn_alias.Id=ext_alias.Id);
```

You can use any of the above queries but NOT Exists query is faster than Not In query.